# Why is my brick material distorted around some of my faces?

Tags: mesh, materials, uv

I'm trying to make a simple mesh of a brick room with a corridor. For some reason, it gets squished by the faces at back and front, and I can't figure out why. Also, when I unwrap, some of the faces will rotate the texture by 90 degrees. I'm hoping to be able to bake this material once I fix it so I can bring this into Unreal (I know some people prefer to do there textures in Unreal, but I just prefer Blender), so it's trickier trying to mess with the UVs.

Here is the front of the corridor:

[image: Front of the corridor]

Here is the back of the room (notice the material here is rotated 90 degrees):

[image: Back of the room]

Part of wall next to corridor entrance:

[image: Part of wall next to corridor entrance.]

And here are my nodes:

[image: Nodes]

I just want to know out how to make the texture consistent with the normal parts throughout the mesh. I've looked around everywhere but couldn't find an answer.

Anyway, this is my first post on Blender Stack Exchange, so sorry if I made any errors.

Any help is appreciated!

Edit: [I forgot to add my project file.](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/516186842094108677/1169013707083358298/mainroom.blend?ex=6553dbda&is=654166da&hm=e3f6768ed9f9ea4b42c8974ef96383e42dffb5f49fb2b421e4adce70417699cb&)

Comment: hello please pack your image and share your file

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what you mean; I have a link to my project at the bottom of this post.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems here, first the UVs are not proportional:

[image]

And second thing, you've also a not proportional scale in the *Mapping* node:

[image]

So what you could do is unwrap again, maybe mark seam, don't forget this one, apply the scale and unwrap:

[image]

and bring back the *Mapping* to a proportional scale:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton! I see that in the way the mesh has been unwrapped, it's going outside the image. Will this be a problem if I want to bake my texture later on?

Comment: no, the image is repeated if the Repeat option is selected in the Image Texture node

Comment: Alright. I tried you suggestions but I ran into some issues.

First, I marked seam, but normal unwrapping made things distorted, and both smart and cube project left me with the same issues as before, but now this time [the side walls are stretched instead of the smaller walls.](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/516186842094108677/1169027901799288862/image.png?ex=6553e913&is=65417413&hm=2931c6f9823a5ae0c4d9b5cd2ef041af0f1e651f8922d082cb47ee4f917d25f4&) I straightened out the scaling but it seems like 40 was way too big so I went with 10. Also, the back and front walls are still rotated.

Comment: See my edit, maybe don't forget the seam I show and also apply the scale before the unwrap?

Comment: Everything seems good now, but it seems like [I have my UVs overlapping each other.](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/516186842094108677/1169095034809876540/image.png?ex=65542799&is=6541b299&hm=28b235f99e446e26b71b59adce6506f3f9d386d9e5e57d146698914a6530ab58&) Is that going to be an issue for baking as well?

Comment: no it should not be an issue